# Google Play 64 bit Requirement Gamemaker Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, game-maker-studio-2

I have trouble adding an app I made in Gamemaker Studio 2 to Google Play; the only things I'm able to modify is the version of Android and the paths to SDK, JDK, and NDK. I can select the architecture of the device: Armv7, x86, Arm64, x86_64. However, selecting just one of the architectures doesn't seem to affect it. So I'd like some advice or tips on what I can do; any help would be greatly appreciated.

From threads and links, people have said the same things to meet the new requirements. However, I do not know what Flutter is; it seems to be an IDE or a terminal of some sort. They all say to make some modifications to "Gradle". Is the Gradle file similar to a txt file, with directions?

I keep seeing [recommendations like this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32191):

```
add following line app level build.gradle
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

run flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm
upload 32bit version to play store
increment versionCode in pubspec.yaml
run flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
upload 64bit version to play store
```

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471011/google-play-64-bit-requirement-issue):

```
defaultConfig {
         ....
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', "armeabi"
    }
```

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982981/how-to-build-app-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement):

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

I've found multiple Gradle directories; I'm using NVPACK and NVIDIA:

- C:\NVPACK\gradle-4.4.1\bin
- C:\NVIDIA\CodeWorksforAndroid\gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip\gradle-4.4.1\bin

Do I modify one of these? What is the specific file path to the desired Gradle?

The contents of these gradle files: [image: An example of what I'm seeing]

Comment: You should generate your APK for both Arm7 and Arm64. When people say "the gradle files" they mean `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`, which (I assume) GMS2 did not create for you.

Comment: Like using the checkbox option with in Gamemaker Studio? Or do you mean modifying the gradle file by typing this: ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'? Does it matter where I type that within that gradle file? Also is the gradle file usually created with or beside the APK file? It'd be helpful if you can be more specific

Answer (score 1):

You usually do not need to modify build.gradle file; Gamemaker Studio 2 comes with its own settings and lets you modify most settings within the GMS2 IDE itself.

It seems that you're aware of your Android SDK/NDK/JDK settings, so I'd assume that you can build an apk or aab already. If not, or if you're not sure, please read the official guides here: [Setting Up For Android](https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001368727-Setting-Up-For-Android-or-Amazon-Fire)

When uploading to Google Play what you normally need to do is to check your build settings. You set up the package ID (com.yourdomain.yourgame), increment your versionCode, and select your target architecture within GMS2 IDE, and the settings are carried into your result .apk or .aab file for you to upload to Google Play Console.

When generating the .apk for Google Play Console, you usually select all 4 architectures before hitting the "create executable" button.
[Official manual page](https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001624867-Android-Compiling-Your-App):